# Are there any tricks to find an orthonormal basis for polynomials by hand?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, integration, numerical-methods

I am taking a Numerical Analysis class. On a previous exam, there is a question which involved finding an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{P}_2$ w.r.t the inner product $(u, v) = \int_0^2 u(t)v(t) dt.$ I did this with Gram-Schmidt, and it took me about $15-20$ minutes (and this was only half a question!). Plus I of course made arithmetic mistakes, and I tired myself out working at $100 \%$ speed. Along the way, I had to solve integrals such as 
$$\int_0^2 \left((x-\frac 34)^2 - \frac {21}{16} \right)^2 dx$$
which take long and are very prone to mistakes. The only thing I could think of was to make a u substitution, $u = x-3/4$.

I am wondering: I applied Gram-Schmidt to $\{1, x, x^2 \}$; is this the way to go, or is there a better way? (I have seen the 3-term reccurence, but it seems like a lot of memorization, and seems to involve a lot of integrals too).

Also, when I do Gram-Schmidt, I orthogonalize, and then normalize everything at the end. Is it better to normalize along the way?

Lastly, if Gram-Schmidt is the way to go, would you have any advice on how to quickly evaluate these types of integrals that come out of Gram-Schmidt? (integrals of polynomials of low degree, often squared).

Thank you very much, I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Some simplification occurs by shifting the interval to $[-1, 1]$ through the substitution $t=x+1$. Equivalently, start with the basis $\{1, x-1, (x-1)^2\}$. The first two vectors are orthogonal.

Comment: There's of course the obvious... don't do it by hand!  It's rather ironic that a *numerical analysis* class won't let you use a computer.

Comment: Another possibility is that you were supposed to have memorized the first few [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) and then realized that you just had to shift them.

Comment: Advice on how to quickly evaluate integrals?...... Mathematica :)